# Replace value across multiple lines in bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm struggling even with all the examples available on stackoverflow and google.

Basically i have the following text

```
    /start r.start ""
      GAIN 0x256 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x256 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end
```

and i need to read through this file searching for a name e.g. r.start which is passed as $1 and substitute e.g. 0x256 with a value that i pass as $2.
There a two instance to substitute, line 2 and line 7.

Things i know:

1. /start is preceded by 4 spaces
2. GAIN is preceded by 6 spaces
3. \r\n or \n might be present
4. CODE is preceded by 8 spaces

Till now i've reached this point

```
pattern="N;s\s\/start r.start \"\"\n      GAIN 0x\(.*\)"
replacement"\/start r.start \"\"\n      GAIN 0x82"
sed -e "$pattern/$replacement/p" test.txt
```

but i get nothing.
I was also able to substitute the first line but for whatever reason it pasted me the first two lines twice on top of each other

the expected value assuming the following call

```
./run.sh r.start 0x284569
```

should be

```
    /start r.start ""
      GAIN 0x284569 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x284569 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end
```

Here's my best shot for the second part

```
var="r.start"
val="0x48209F82"

pattern="\(CODE \"$var\" \).*\(.*\)"
replacement="\1$val\2"
sed "s/$pattern/$replacement/g" test.txt
```

The problem is that it is deleting everything after the value substitution. I can't put in \2 the following chars

EDIT:

By doing the following

```
var="r.start"
val="0x48209F82"

pattern="\(CODE \"$var\" \).*\(\s.*\s.*\s.*\)"
replacement="\1$val\2"
sed "s/$pattern/$replacement/g" test.txt
```

I get what i want but it feels a little bit dirty, how do i reduce the last part in case of a variable number of char? Can i just somehow match everything till end of line?

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @Luigi : Since your code did not work as expected, you should pass your code too.

Comment: @Luigi : Since you have to look at a certain section in the file and do a lot of parsing in the lines, I wouldn't do this with _bash_. _awk_ also is feasible only if you have a fixed number of fields in every line, but for instance if the parameter after `CODE` may have spaces insided the quotes, you are out of luck again. To find the best tool for the job, the starting point would be to define the exact syntax for the lines in question.

Comment: Hello the parameter after CODE has no spaces inside as it is the name of a variable basically. So it can't contain spaces. From my pov after finding CODE i just need to "skip" whatever is inside the double quotes and subtitute from 0x to a space (right before 0x2). The idea is that after i find the main block /start i dont really care of the second name let's say but still a double check would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like the following? It uses a `sed` range to select everything between the `/start` and `/end`, and within the range uses a block to substitute the value for lines which match `GAIN` and `CODE`.

```
$ cat foo.txt
    /start r.start ""
      GAIN 0x256 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x256 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end
$ sed '\#/start r\.start#,\#/end#{/\(GAIN\|CODE "r\.start"\)/s/0x[a-fA-F0-9]\+/0x284569/}' foo.txt
    /start r.start ""
      GAIN 0x284569 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x284569 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end
```

The `sed` script looks like this when formatted nicely:

```
\#/start r\.start#,\#/end# {
    /\(GAIN\|CODE "r\.start"\)/s/0x[a-fA-F0-9]\+/0x284569/
}
```

Note

- the use of `\#...#` instead of `/.../` for the range patterns, so we don't have to quote slashes
- the use of `/patten1/s/pattern2/string/` to replace `pattern2` only for lines containing `pattern1`
- the use of a `{...}` block so that the substitution only applies between `/start` and `/end`

You can parameterise the pattern and value like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

var='r\.start'
val='0x48209F82'

sed '\#/start '$var'#,\#/end#{/\(GAIN\|CODE "'$var'"\)/s/0x[0-9a-fA-F]\+/'$val'/}' foo.txt
```

Comment: Works nicely, could you break down each token? I find it quite hard to understand

Comment: Also what if the value is just 0x and not 0x[0-9a-fA-F] how do i set it so that it may or may not be present? Changed to 0x[0-9a-fA-F]* and worked fine

Comment: I've added an explanation of the sed script. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^    \/start r\.start /{:a;N;/^    \/end$/M!ba;s/^(      GAIN |        CODE "r\.start" )0x\S+/\10x284569/Mg}' file
```

Gather up lines between `/start` and `/end` and using pattern matching replace the desired values.

The solution may be placed in a function:

```
f () { sed -E '/^    \/start '"$1"' /{:a;N;/^    \/end$/M!ba;s/^(      GAIN |        CODE "'"$1"'" )0x\S+/\1'"$2"'/Mg}' "$3"; }
```

And called:

```
f r\\.start 0x284569 file
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't  made myself clear, 0x256 is just a place holder, the idea is to substitute whatever value is present between 0x and a space

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

# retrieve the 2 parameters
my $start = shift @ARGV or die "missing 1rst arg";
my $repl =  shift @ARGV or die "missing 2nd arg";

# input file
open my $fh_in, '<', 'file.txt' or die "$!";
# output file
open my $fh_out, '>', 'output' or die "$!";

# loop through input file
while(<$fh_in>) {
    # if we are between /start {1srt parameter} and /end
    if (/^ {4}\/start\h+$start/ ... /^ {4}\/end\h*$/) {
        # substitute 0x.... by {2nd parameter}
        s/^(?: {6}GAIN | {8}CODE "$start" )\K0x\w+/$repl/;
    }
    print $fh_out $_;
}
```

**In action:**

```
cat file.txt 
    /start other.start ""
      GAIN 0x256 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x256 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end
    /start r.start ""
      GAIN 0x256 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x256 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end

./test.pl r.start 0x123456

cat output 
    /start other.start ""
      GAIN 0x256 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x256 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end
    /start r.start ""
      GAIN 0x123456 __POSITIVE 1 FOO
      OTHER
      OTHER
      /start MACRO
        200
        CODE "r.start" 0x123456 0x2 10 0xA3
      /end MACRO
      OTHER
    /end
```

Answer (score -1):

You want sed for this, and don't need a script:

Assuming the text is a file called the_text:

```
sed "s/0x256/REPLACETEXT/g" the_text
```

If you ant to do that with out echoing out the text then add a -i

```
sed -i "s/0x256/REPLACETEXT/g" the_text
```

It is possible to daisy chain these commands or embed them into single script, this one echoes to the standard out:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed "s/0x256/${2}/g" $1
sed "s/0x256/${2}/g" $1
```

Comment: 0x256 is as stated above an example (e.g.) but may vary in length as well

Comment: @Toby Batch: This would replace 0x256 everywhere in the file and not only in the r.start section.